# Archimesh " Operator does not work in edit mode "

Tags: modeling, mesh, archimesh-add-on

When I edit the size of the object image in the room generator the image / object disappears, even the scene of the room part disappears.

It shows a warning on the room generator

> The operator does not work in edit mode

Where is the error and what is the solution?

Comment: Please post questions in English on BSE.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after I edited a window on the mesh level. Somehow it got stuck in edit mode there. After I selected the mesh again and then selected something else it went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely in *Object Isolated Mode*; press <kbd>NUMPAD  /</kbd> and try again!